# Trigger the event for another element

Tags: jquery

I need to trigger the one event for another
for example

```
Click
```

to another like

```
  next click
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please give a more accurate description of the problem? Do you mean 'Click' **automatically triggers a chain of events?** or Do you want **an event triggered with Each Click**?

Comment: i have done some code in jquery for "click" and same as the function will work for "click next"

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstElement = $('.yourFirstElem');
var secondElement = $('.yourSecondElem');

firstElement.on('click', function () {
secondElement.click();
})
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually won't help the OP to understand their problem.